# Remove disabled attribute of INPUT tag with Jsoup?

Tags: java, jsoup

I have an HTML string, where I have a text box, and what I want is to remove the disabled attribute by its ID.

```
String baseHtml = "<div id='stylized' class='myform'>"
+ "<input id='txt_question' disabled='disabled' name='preg' type='text' style='width:150px;'>"
+ "</div>";

Document doc = Jsoup.parse(baseHtml);
Elements elements = doc.getElementById("txt_question").select("input");
elements.remove();
elements = doc.select("input");
System.out.println(doc.outerHtml());
```

The problem is that it erases all INPUT tag, what I want is to take only the disabled attribute.
Can you help me please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Elements#select](http://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/select/Elements.html#select%28java.lang.String%29) supports [CSS selectors](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp) so you can do it as follows:

```
Elements elementTxtQuestion = doc.select("#txt_question"); // selects element with Id 'txt_question'
elementTxtQuestion.removeAttr("disabled"); // removes attribute 'disabled'
```

You can find more information here: [Use selector-syntax to find elements](http://jsoup.org/cookbook/extracting-data/selector-syntax).